# I need a C# function that will convert from one row format to another?

Tags: c#

I have to do following kind of conversions where my source string can have one or two periods and where each number is represented by two digits. So a "1" becomes "01" and a "90" becomes "90". Here's an example of the before -> after

```
0.0 -> 0000
1.1 -> 0101
10.10 -> 1010
1.88 -> 0188
1.11.22 -> 011122
33.44.5 -> 334405
```

I have the following function but it does work for the different combinations. Can anyone suggest how I can make it work for the case where there are **1 or 2** periods in my input:

```
    public string DotFormatToRowKey(string tempRowKey) {
        return string.Join("", from s in id.Split('.')
                               select s.PadLeft(2, '0')).PadRight(4, '0'));
    }
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your function? Can you provide sample, where output is incorrect? I can see problem only where you don't have dots in your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
public string DotFormatToRowKey(string tempRowKey) {
        var splits = tempRowKey.Split('.') // Split string at "."
                     .Select(x => String.Format("{0:d2}", Int32.Parse(x))) // Specify string format
                     .ToList();
        return String.Join(String.Empty, splits.ToArray()); // Join array and return
}
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd260048.aspx

Comment: Now I am confused because of the other answer which doesn't use PadRight :-(

Comment: @JamesHill actually PadRight does nothing in your code, because it applied after string was already padded to total length 2.

Comment: Yups the `PadRight` is not required here

Comment: Thanks. So I think everyone agrees your solution is okay or should I remove the PadRight from yours?

Comment: @Anne, Since it appears my initial answer wasn't optimal, I've updated my post with a new solution.

Comment: @JamesHill don't you think int parse is a bit of over kill in this case ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta, no, I don't. Don't you think you're being a bit critical in this case? For the string formatting to work, you must pass an int. I'm just showing another way to approach this. You're padding strings, I'm formatting them.

Answer (score 2):

I Think you just need `PadLeft(2,'0')` part only

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", "1.33.45".Split('.').Select(ech => ech.PadLeft(2, '0')).ToArray())); 
 //Outputs: 334405
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", "1.1".Split('.').Select(ech => ech.PadLeft(2, '0')).ToArray()));
//Outputs: 0101
```

Split will get you the parts and if required Pad it up with zeros and your length is `2` as in examples shown

```
return (string.Join("", tempRowKey.Split('.').Select(ech => ech.PadLeft(2, '0')).ToArray()) ;
```

Comment: @V4 - I'm a bit confused. Should that be a pad right or a pad left. James was saying PadRight but

Comment: If you say `PadRight` then `33.44.5` -> `334450` which is not what you want (`0` is padded on the Right part of the string)

Comment: So I should just remove all of ".PadRight(4, '0')" ?

Comment: @V4Vendetta PadRight applied to joined string, not for each part of string. There is no problem with OP's code if at least one dot will be in input.

Comment: @JamesHill Unless you are using Right to Left it won't be possible

Comment: @JamesHill Ok you have `PadRight` later (thanks lazyberezovsky) but don't think its needed and for the record your solution should work.

Comment: @V4Vendetta - I'm sorry again but now I am even more confused. Is the answer James gave okay? Now he has a different answer and my head's spinning.

Comment: @V4Vendetta - If I was to use your solution in a method like mine then can you show me what it would look like? I just want something simple and I'm still a bit confused :-)